# laravel 5.8 bootstrap not working inside Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-5

i am using https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

its working fine in view but when i using this in Jquery below code its not working. help me to fix this.

view code php

```
      <table id="tableAppointment" style="background-color:powderblue;">
     
        <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">NAME</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;" colspan="1">HSN/SAC</th>
       
       
      <th><a href="#" class="addRow btn btn-warning vertical-center"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
  plus">ADD</i></a></th>
      </tr>
       
       <tr>
        <td >
    
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  name="product_name[]">
           <option value=""></option>
          @foreach ($addnewitem as $key=>$addnewitems)
            <option  >{{$addnewitems->product_name}}</option> 
          @endforeach </select>
    
        </td>
    
     
        <td >
              <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  name="part_no[]">
           <option value=""></option>
          @foreach ($addnewitem as $key=>$addnewitems)
            <option  >{{$addnewitems->part_no}}</option> 
          @endforeach </select>
    
        </td>
    
         <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger "><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">REMOVE</i></a> 
  </td>
      </tr>
    
    </table>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $('.addRow').on('click',function(){
            addRow();
        });
        function addRow()
        {
        
            var tr='<tr>'+
    
    
            '<td ><select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  name="product_name[]"><option 
 value=""></option> @foreach($addnewitem as $key=>$addnewitems)<option  >{{$addnewitems->product_name}}</option>@endforeach </select></td>'+
    
    
    
             
'<td ><select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"  name="part_no[]"><option value=""></option> 
  @foreach($addnewitem as $key=>$addnewitems)<option  >{{$addnewitems->part_no}}</option>@endforeach 
 </select></td>'+
    
    
           
            
 '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">REMOVE</i></a> 
 </td>'+
         
            '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        };
        $('.remove').live('click',function(){
            var last=$('tbody tr').length;
            if(last==1){
                alert("you can not remove last row");
            }
            else{
                 $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            }
        
        });
    
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: The comments and answer in [your duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63577504/laravel-5-8-bootstrap-not-working-in-jquery) did not help?

Comment: @kerbh0lz not its not worked

Comment: @kerbh0lz its not helped

Comment: Yeah I get it. Really no reason to start the same question again, people can still discuss/help in your duplicate question

Comment: @kerbh0lz i am trying to slow this problem,

Comment: @kerbh0lz  you have php, laravel. sass, vue. knowledge please help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is of much help but from your code

```php
@foreach ($addnewitem as $key=>$addnewitems)
    <option>{{$addnewitems->part_no}}</option> 
@endforeach
```

Shouldn't it be `{{$key->part_no}}` as in, key points to value instead of you pointing the value to another value in `{{$addnewitesm->part_no}}`.

Can we see the sample or dd() of the data you are trying to iterate? and why are you not using `foreach($addnewitem as $newitem)` because by implying that `key => value`, then it means that you are directly accessing your values, which means for example

```php
//array
$array = array("name" => "example", "age" => 26);
//in this case i can iterate by saying that key => value
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "$key=$value"
}
//output
name=example
age=26
```

Comment: this is just an form i am using this to store data. i am not showing any data from database