# The first optgroup of select picker is getting copied on all the optgroups

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a select picker multiple dropdown working on fine, but when I add the optgroups the second, third are all copied by the first optgroup values.

The opt-groups are getting populated via js.

```
<select class="modal-input selectpicker" style="width: 75%;" data-live-search="true"
            aria-label="Select TestCases" id="select-options" multiple disabled>
</select>
```

The JS used is.

```
$("#select-options").html("")
$("#select-options").html(`
    <optgroup label="First">
        <option>Option One</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Second">
        <option>Option Two</option>
        <option>Option Three</option>
    </optgroup>
`)
$("#select-options").selectpicker("refresh");
```

The output I get is

[image]

The optgroup labels seems to work but the options are getting copied, I also checked the brouser inspect element the select input seems to be populated fine. The selectpicker is copying the same data in both the groups.

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205248/jquery-bootstrap-selectpicker-refreshing-lists-based-upon-previous-list-choice

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have clearly added $("#select-options").selectpicker("refresh"); after updating the list. And the select picker did get refreshed the only thing is it is copying the items from group1 into group2

Comment: Someone recommended to had a `$(".selectpicker").selectpicker();` **before** changing the options. Did you try that too?

Comment: Yes, the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, resolved it by reverting to the previous version of the CDN for selectpicker

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need still help here, but the issue is caused by bootstrap. If you need to use selectpicker with optgroup tag you need to use at least 1.14.0-beta3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js. If you use previous versions the first optgroup will be copied to all others optgroups