Bootstrap mulitselect selected items not working after AJAX call
I am having an issue with Boostrap multi-select selected count not working after my AJAX call.
I have a parent list that I make multiple selections from, which then sends an AJAX call to retrieve the ids and text of the child list.
I am using JSON data to append additional checkboxes (li items) on the success function of my call. I also am adding the <option> items to my select as I thought that would have fixed the issue.
For some reason, now, when I click a checkbox in my new child list of the new checkboxes, the label in the control is not keeping a record of my selected count.
Can anyone help me understand what I am missing? I have seen some recommendations to re-initialize multi-select after creating my list items, but this has not made a difference.


$jq.ajax({
  async: false,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'Messages.aspx/GetSeriesforFormIds',
  data: "{'data':'" + JSON.stringify(formIds) + "'}",
  success: function(data) {
    //debugger;
    if (data.d != null) {
      var $checkboxContainer = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes .multiselect-container');

      var temp = data.d;

      if (temp != '') {
        //debugger;
        var obj = $.parseJSON(temp);

        debugger;
        var $container = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes select');

        if ((obj != '') && (obj.data.length > 0)) {
          for (i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
            $container.append('<option value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</option>')
            $checkboxContainer.append('<li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</label ></a ></li >')
          }
        }
      }
    }
    debugger;
    //$('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes select').multiselect('reload');
  },
  error: function(response) {
    //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
});
<select size="4" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlchkSeries$ddlListBox" multiple="multiple" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlchkSeries_ddlListBox" class="ddlchkBox form-control form-select" style="display: none;">
  <option value="30">EDB</option>
  <option value="31">JDBW</option>
  <option value="32">KLD</option>
  <option value="72">JDSW</option>
  <option value="84">KLD2</option>
  <option value="30">EDB</option>
  <option value="31">JDBW</option>
  <option value="32">KLD</option>
  <option value="58">CMB</option>
  <option value="72">JDSW</option>
  <option value="84">KLD2</option>
</select>



The Html checkboxes that are created in the ajax success and are not working with multi select:
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu show" style="position: absolute; inset: auto auto 0px 0px; margin: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, -30.5455px, 0px);" data-popper-placement="top-start">
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="30">EDB</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="31">JDBW</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="32">KLD</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="72">JDSW</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="84">KLD2</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="30">EDB</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="31">JDBW</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="32">KLD</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="58">CMB</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="72">JDSW</label></a></li>
   <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="84">KLD2</label></a></li>
</ul>


Please edit your question to show the HTML containing the checkboxes that you are appending to. It would really help us to see a minimal reproducible example of the problem.

maybe check out this see if helos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205248/jquery-bootstrap-selectpicker-refreshing-lists-based-upon-previous-list-choice

@PatrickHume your comment put me on the right track. The solution was $('#ddlListBox').multiselect('rebuild'); as refresh didn't work, but 'reload' did the trick. Thank you!

glad it helped ;)

UPDATE: The solution to my issue was to use $('#ddlListBox').multiselect('rebuild'); immediately following the addition of my new checkbox controls still insude the success function of the AJAX call.
$jq.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'Messages.aspx/GetSeriesforFormIds',
                    data: "{'data':'" + JSON.stringify(formIds) + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //debugger;
                        if (data.d != null) {


                            var $checkboxContainer = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes .multiselect-container');
                            $checkboxContainer.html("");
                           
                            var temp = data.d;

                            if (temp != '') {

                                //debugger;
                                var obj = $.parseJSON(temp);

                                //debugger;
                                var $container = $('.ddlchkSeriesCheckboxes select');
                                $container.html("");
                                if ((obj != '') && (obj.data.length > 0)) {
                                    for (i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
                                        $container.append('<option value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</option>')
                                        $checkboxContainer.append('<li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="' + obj.data[i].Id + '">' + obj.data[i].text + '</label ></a ></li >')
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        
                        debugger;
                        $('#ddlListBox').multiselect('rebuild');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                });

